# Is there any difference between auto and __auto_type?

Tags: c++, c, keyword, type-inference, auto

I've been using `__auto_type` in C for sometime now and I was wondering if it's any different from `auto` in C++. Are they implemented differently?

I've tried searching for this, but it doesn't yield any results, since searching for ***__auto_type in C*** returns articles about `auto` in C++. It feels like a forgotten keyword.

Comment: `__auto_type` does not compile in my C++ code.

Comment: It's a GNU extension https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html - and C only, yes

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Would you like to post that as an answer?

Comment: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2953.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As StoryTeller commented, it's a GCC extension in C mode. It doesn't work in C++

> In GNU C, but not GNU C++, you may also declare the type of a variable as `__auto_type`. In that case, the declaration must declare only one variable, whose declarator must just be an identifier, the declaration must be initialized, and the type of the variable is determined by the initializer; the name of the variable is not in scope until after the initializer. (In C++, you should use C++11 auto for this purpose.) Using `__auto_type`, the “maximum” macro above could be written as:
>
> ```
>    #define max(a,b) \
>      ({ __auto_type _a = (a); \
>      __auto_type _b = (b); \
>      _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
> ```
>
> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

As you can see, it's **not** exactly the same as `auto` in C++ because

- it can only be used to declare a single variable, while `auto` in C++ can be used to declare multiple variables like `auto i = 0, *p = &i;`
- it can't appear in the return type or arguments of a function (or lambda) like `auto f();` or `void f(auto);`

It can't also replace `auto` in case of `decltype(auto)`, or be used like `const auto& i = expr;` because there are no such features in C

However later Clang adopted this keyword and **also supports it in C++** where it's **exactly the same as `auto`** and it can even be used for C++98

> This implementation differs from GCC's in also supporting `__auto_type` in C++,
> treating it the same as `auto`. I don't see any good reason not to, because
> otherwise headers intended to be used from both languages can't use it (you
> could use a define that expands to `__auto_type` or `auto` depending on the
> language, but then C++ pre-11 is broken).
>
> [Add support for GCC's '__auto_type' extension.](https://reviews.llvm.org/D12686)

[Demo for Clang++](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:13),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++__auto_type++x+%3D+4%3B%0A++++__auto_type++y+%3D+3.37%3B%0A++++__auto_type++ptr+%3D+%26x%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+typeid(x).name()+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%0A++++++++++++++%3C%3C+typeid(y).name()+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%0A++++++++++++++%3C%3C+typeid(ptr).name()+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A+%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.581196581196586,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1100,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O1%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+11.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:53.41880341880342,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

It's also supported in [Objective C](https://twitter.com/armadsen/status/742812778512015361)